# Find number of jobs waiting for thread from executor service pool (JAVA)?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a server that has multiple worker threads implemented using java executorService (ie. a thread pool)

My problem is that I am not able to log at every second, the length of jobs waiting to be processed if there is no idle thread available from the thread pool.

NOTE : Logging is not my problem but I want to be able to see how many tasks/jobs are waiting to be processed by a worker thread, is there anyway to see the length of the waiting queue (not the thread pool ) inside executor service?

I have no idea how to implement this thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor accepts a `BlockingQueue` parameter which is the `Queue` implementation used to store the waiting jobs. You can request this queue using `getQueue()` method, then check the size of the queue:

```
System.out.println("Number of waiting jobs: "+executor.getQueue().size());
```

Note that this method is not available in the `ExecutorService` interface, thus it's better to construct the `ThreadPoolExecutor` explicitly instead of using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` and friends:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

While `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` in OpenJDK/OracleJDK does the same, it's not specified, thus using `(ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` may cause `ClassCastException` in future Java versions or alternative JDK implementations.

Comment: is there also a way to get the number of threads waiting to poll some resource from an arrayblockingqueue?

Comment: @LoveMeow, I doubt. But you may check other methods of `ThreadPoolExecutor` like `getTaskCount()`, `getActiveCount()`, etc. Probably thay will answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you can assume that the `ExecutorService` implementation used by your server is `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then you can use the method `getQueue()` that returns the number of tasks that have not been assigned to a `Worker` yet.

```
/**
 * Returns the task queue used by this executor. Access to the
 * task queue is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring.
 * This queue may be in active use.  Retrieving the task queue
 * does not prevent queued tasks from executing.
 *
 * @return the task queue
 */
public BlockingQueue<Runnable> getQueue() {
    return workQueue;
}
```

So you can run something like this:

```
 if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("Pending tasks: %d", executor.getQueue().size()));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion use ThreadPoolExecutor instead of ExecutorService.
You can take advantage of the blocking queue present in the ThreadPoolExecutor class. This would give you the count of threads waiting.

Also ThreadPoolExecutor class is having methods to get the count of submitted tasks and executed task.

Refer the

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

[BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping a counter of the tasks added to the pool and a counter of the tasks completed/started by the pool. Simple and works with any threading paradigm.